# AnsiString and += operator

Tags: c++builder, vcl

this very little code fragment is heavily confusing me, although I'm only trying to concatenate to strings.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    AnsiString HelloWorld = "Hello ";
    HelloWorld += "World";

    TStringList *sl1 = new TStringList();
    sl1->Add("Hello");
    sl1->Strings[0] += " World";

    TStringList *sl2 = new TStringList();
    sl2->Add("Hello");
    sl2->Strings[0] = sl2->Strings[0] + " World";

    Memo1->Lines->Add( HelloWorld );         // prints "Hello World"
    Memo1->Lines->Add( sl1->Strings[0] );    // prints "Hello"  =====> WHY?
    Memo1->Lines->Add( sl2->Strings[0] );    // prints "Hello World"
}
```

Is the operator += not working on TStringList items?

What would be the proper way to do so?

Comment: FYI, in the newer [CLang based C++ compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers), you *CAN* [use compound operators like `+=` on properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Differences_Between_Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers_and_Previous-Generation_C%2B%2B_Compilers#property:_Compound_and_Chained_Assignment) and they do the right thing. The "classic" C++ compilers do not.

Comment: `sl1->Strings[0]` is in fact translated (by the classic compiler) to `sl1->Strings->GetItem(0)`, and using += on such a result doesn't make sense, as that only modifies the anonymous function result, and not the original in the list. The new Clang compilers recognize the situation and do: `sl1->Strings->SetItem(sl1->Strings->GetItem(0) + " World"));`.

Comment: In other word, += does not (always) work on properties, when you use the classic compiler. In the Clang compilers, it does. Note that in 10.3 Rio, for Win32, the Clang compiler is the default and you must change the project options if you want to use the classic Borland compiler. For Win64, there is only the Clang compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you use Strings[0] you are actually accessing a Property, and not the actual string. As such, when you use

```
sl1->Strings[0] += " World";
```

what is really happening is that you are invoking the read method for the property Strings, which is then resulting a string. On that resulting string, you are concatenating something else.

This is not changing the property's inner string at all.

In this case, just for the sake of understanding how it works, you could think that reading

```
sl1->Strings[0]
```

is the same as calling a function that returns a string (and in fact, it is! Because when you read a property it is running it's read method).